# How to arrange existing keys in HashMap with keys of my own?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have a certain HashMap whereby the key represents the order of the ClassModel. As we all know, HashMaps do not maintain the order of the keys when it is retrieved or outputted. I also have an ArrayList whereby it stores the intended order of arrangement of the ClassModels. For example, when I retrieve the key values from the Hashmap, I would get something like Car 1, Car 4, Car 3, Car 5 and Car 2. The ArrayList values instead has the intended order of arrangement values; Car 1, Car 2, Car 3, Car 4 and Car 5. I would like to order them according the keys in the ArrayList. My code is below:

```
    for (HashMap.Entry<String, FloorPlanModel> existingKeys : floorPlanKeys.entrySet()) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "existingKeys entries = " + existingKeys.getKey());
    }
    for (String newKeys : buildingModel.getFpKeys()) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "newKeys entries = " + newKeys);
    }
```

And the outputs are the moment are:

```
existingKeys entries = floorplan0
existingKeys entries = floorplan2
existingKeys entries = floorplan3
existingKeys entries = floorplan4
existingKeys entries = floorplan1

newKeys entries = floorplan0
newKeys entries = floorplan1
newKeys entries = floorplan2
newKeys entries = floorplan3
newKeys entries = floorplan4
```

I am supposed to put the second for loop inside the first for loop, but how do iterate over each values in the HashMap and order them with the one in ArrayList? If I overwrite them, will the values in the hashmap change?

I forgot to mention that I am unable to use TreeMaps for this. I would need to manually arrange them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is your friend. Map with sorted/sortable keys.

Comment: Ok I forgot to mention that I am unable to use TreeMaps at the moment due to retrieving the data from Firebase (which only stores the data in HashMaps) and inputting it straight into a ExpandableListAdapter (whereby the I have to insert the values into the child and group, which takes in the position in integers). So I would have iterate them and rearrange them manually instead.

Comment: `new TreeMap(myHashMap)` will convert it.